# How To Calculate Elliptic Curve Pairing Function Given BLS Public Key and Message

Tags: rust, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to calculate curve pairings for the BLS cryptosystem given a public key and message. I generate the key with the [bls_signatures](https://docs.rs/bls-signatures/0.10.0/bls_signatures/) crate and ultimately want to crunch `e(pub_key, HashToCurve(message))` using the [blstrs](https://docs.rs/blstrs/0.3.0/blstrs/) crate (since I found [a pairing function](https://docs.rs/blstrs/0.3.0/blstrs/fn.pairing.html) there).

```
let priv_key = bls_signatures::PrivateKey::new(&[0_u8; 32]);  // not secure, but repeatable

let mut buff = std::io::Cursor::new(vec![]);

let _bytes_written = priv_key
    .public_key()
    .as_affine()
    .write_raw(&mut buff);
    
let mut pub_key_affine_bytes: Vec<u8> = buff.into_inner();
```

The first problem is that `paired::bls12_381::G1Affine::write_raw()` seems to be adding an extraneous zero to the beginning, giving me 97 bytes instead of 96:

```
assert!(pub_key_affine_bytes.len() == 97_usize);  // instead of 96
assert!(pub_key_affine_bytes[0] == 0_u8); // regardless of key used... which seems wrong
```

I can "fix" it for now via `let _ = pub_key_affine_bytes.remove(0);` but when I try to convert to a `blstrs::G1Affine` (in the hopes of using [blstrs::pairing()](https://docs.rs/blstrs/0.3.0/blstrs/fn.pairing.html) to reach my goal, but maybe there's a better way?), the blstrs library doesn't like it:

```
let pub_key_affine_bytes: [u8; 96] = pub_key_affine_bytes.try_into().unwrap();
assert!(blstrs::G1Affine::from_uncompressed(&pub_key_affine_bytes) == None);    // instead of Some(_)
```

It's probably obvious by now, but I'm new to both Rust and this type of cryptography, so any guidance is welcome. How would you calculate pairings given a public key and message?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [ffi](https://crates.io/crates/blst) behind blstrs? At least there you can reference the C API, and there are some helpful code snippets in the [benches](https://github.com/supranational/blst/blob/master/bindings/rust/benches/blst_benches.rs) and [tests](https://github.com/supranational/blst/blob/48f69febca82082298f18e31509670b20f64f2ed/bindings/rust/src/lib.rs#L1153)

Comment: Thanks for the links but I've searched thoroughly without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized this simple solution as I was done looking through all the source code and writing up my original answer. It's as easy as changing the enabled features in your `Cargo.toml` to disable the usage of `paired` and enable `blstrs` to be used internally.

```
[package]
name = "blst_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
blstrs = "^0.3"
bls-signatures = {version="0.10.0", default-features= false, features=["blst"] }
```

With that fixed, the following works just fine

```rust
fn main() {

    let priv_key = bls_signatures::PrivateKey::new(&[0_u8; 32]);  // not secure, but repeatable

    let affine = priv_key
        .public_key()
        .as_affine(); // blstrs::G1Affine, no longer from paired!
        

    println!("{:?}", affine);
}
```